# Automatic login after they complete the registration form Joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to enable automatic login after the user completes the registration form Joomla 3.4?
Thanks in advance and blessings,

Comment: I think there might be an extension for does just this. Will try and dig it up for you in a bit

Answer (score 4):

I did a plugin to do that some time ago.
You can download it from here:

http://www.webemus.com/en/37-productos/extensiones-joomla/303-joomla-autologin-plugin

It is necesary to set "New User Account Activation" to none in User Manager Options in order the plugin to work

Hope it works for you

Comment: You should submit it to JED to make this easier to be be found

Comment: yes I will, just that most of my web is in Spanish and I have to switch to english before, and you know, we are always short of time.

Comment: Nice to hear that. So far I was the only one that had used it.

Comment: I really, really need this plugin feature - however it appears to be wiping out or not saving extra `User Profile` data (official joomla user profile plugin)